# HTC wildfire clear history does not clear browser history

Tags: android, browser-history, htc-android

I have developed my app to display browser history. I query the `android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` table to fetch data & update my UI. This works well on Google Nexus S, but HTC Wildfire gives some issues. It seems to have a customised browser app & stores history data in its own private tables.

Because if i clear history using "Browser->menu->Bookmarks->History->menu->clear history", my `android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` DOES NOT get cleared.

It only gets cleared if i clear history using "Browser->menu->more->settings->clear history" anyone has idea where does HTC store their history data & how to access it.

Comment: Thanx for editing Lukas, but i would love to see an working answer here .. pl help